# urlencode to lower case in PHP

Tags: php, urlencode, url-encoding, lowercase

In PHP, when url encoding using urlencode(), the outputted characters are in upper case:

```
echo urlencode('MyString'.chr(31));
//returns 'MyString%1F'
```

I need to get PHP to give me back 'MyString%1f' for the above example but not to lower case any other part of the string. in order to be consistent with other platforms. Is there any way I can do this without having to run through the string one character at a time, working out if I need to change the casing each time?

Comment: Looks like the output is still `MyString%1F`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to do this at all? `F` or `f`, it shouldn't make any difference as [percent encoding is ment to be case-insensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.1). The only case I could think of would be when creating hashes, however personally I would then convert the whole string to either uppercase or lowercase, ie treat it as case-insensitive.

Anyways, if you really need to do this, then it should be relatively easy using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$original = 'MyString%1F%E2%FOO%22';
$modified = preg_replace_callback('/%[0-9A-F]{2}/', function(array $matches)
{
    return strtolower($matches[0]);
},
$original);

var_dump($modified);
```

This should give you:

```
string(18) "MyString%1f%e2%FOO%22"
```

Comment: I was replicating an interface and it's responses exactly. Some other differences I've overcome but this had me stumped. I'm trying to use built in functions where possible to minimise overheads and keep up performance.

Comment: That pattern isn't quite right - it matches `<digit><hexletter>` and `<digit><hexletter>` (and so happens to match your examples), but not `<hexletter><hexletter>`. A better pattern is `'/%[0-9A-F]{2}/'`. It's safe because numbers are not affected by `strtolower`.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking @Synchro, of course the pattern is wrong, I'll update my answer.